# Многоточие после слова до конца строки

Tags: jquery, css3, вёрстка, css

Добрый день, уважаемые. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать такую штуку: например есть список `UL li` И мне необходимо, чтобы после текста в теге `li` автоматически подставлялись точки до конца строки. Например так

Текст .....................................................................................

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

1. Делается изображение с нужной точкой внизу строки (одна точка + расстояние до следующей точки).
2. Это изображение вставляется фоном в li с repeat-x.
3. У текста задаётся фон такого же цвета как и основной фон страницы. Возможно чуть подправляются стили, т.о. чтобы фон текста перекрывал фон li и под текстом точек видно не было.

Answer (score 0):

Можно немного проще:

html:

```
<ul>
      <li><span>Текст</span></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul li{ border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;}

ul li span{border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
```

Comment: в 1px [не работает][1], лучше уж [в 3px][2]..


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/6dg2E/28/
  [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/6dg2E/29/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    li:after {
      content: " ....................................................";
      white-space: pre;
    }
    .ulli {
      width: 200px;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ulli">
    <ul>
      <li>один</li>
      <li>два</li>
      <li>три</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Пожалуйста

```js
var items = document.getElementById('list').children;

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].innerHTML = items[i].innerHTML + '.............';
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>Текст 1</li>
    <li>Текст 2</li>
    <li>Текст 3</li>
    <li>Текст 4</li>
</ul>
```

И не надо никакого `jQuery`.

Comment: jQuery может и не надо, но ваш способ вряд ли подойдет ТС. [Увеличиваем в одном из элементов](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/6dg2E/1/) списка кол-во символов и картина становится не лицеприятной.

Comment: @Deonis, однако если [добавить немного CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/6dg2E/2/)... =)

Comment: Вы хоть сами поняли что написали?
Зачем было в код заворачивать просто пристыковывание статичного кол-ва "........"???

Comment: @I_CaR, не надо орать. все я прекрасно понял что написал. а теперь, мистер Гений, предоставьте свой код

Comment: а у @Sh4dow результат выглядит не очень-то красиво, если выделить мышкой любой блок и потянуть направо